# How to reset flutter pre build packages into default?

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

Guys, i change flutter code files by mistake, I received a warning from my IDE, that told me the changed code has been saved!

the problem comes when i got error in my code and the IDE suggest to changed the packages and i clicked it by mistake

So, i want to ask you how do i reset all flutter packages and codes into default? without uninstall flutter, because its hard to re install it again also i don't know how to uninstall flutter

I'm using MacOS, VS Code IDE

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the package is in your `pubspec.yaml` file, at the top of your project's file structure (folder).

When you find the file, locate the `dependencies` section and remove the line where the package you've accidentally installed is present. Note that it might be under the `dev_dependencies` section, depending on what you installed.

You will never need to uninstall Flutter/Dart when one of your projects gets messy.

The extension for VS Code should reload your dependencies (automatically remove it) when you remove the line in `pubspec.yaml`. If it doesn't, you can run `pub get` in the terminal; or press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and search for `Pub: Get packages`. Those commands both do what the automatic changes would do.

Comment: i don't know which code has been changed by mistake, also i tries to write pub get in terminal, i got "bash: pub: command not found"
also, CTRL+SHIFT+P doesn't did anything, to remind you i'm using macOS maybe the shortcut here is not that

one more thing the code that i changed will changed only on this project? or for all project?
because if it will changed in this project only i could create a new project and copy all my code

Comment: You can copy all of your code into a new project, then you should be good to go from there.

Comment: `dart pub get` for flutter